# How does a virtual interface actually route traffic?

Tags: networking, routing

These are the first few lines when I run `netstat -nr`:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc          126        0     en0
10.8.0.1/32        10.8.0.17          UGSc            0        0   utun3
```

When I make a request to anything outside of `10.8.0.1/32` it goes straight to the physical gateway `192.168.1.1`.

What happens to requests going to `10.8.0.17`? This is virtual so I imagine it's handled by some software. This question is actually two very closely related questions:

1. How does my machine actually know what `10.8.0.17` means? In other words, when it sees this as a gateway, what is the immediate next step? (I hope that makes sense)
2. Is there a way for me to examine what handler might be listening in on requests to this interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the gateway at `10.8.0.17` is virtual, so I understand that you have
installed some product on your computer that has created a virtual adapter.

This virtual adapter is supported by a driver that does the magic of emulating
a physical adapter. To the operating system it will basically look like a
[Network interface controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller).

Such a virtual controller has no physical component, so cannot support
[Programmed input/output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmed_input/output)
for transferring data between the CPU and a peripheral.
It will rather use
[Direct memory access (DMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access)
to communicate with the OS network driver, passing commands and data through
the shared memory area allocated by the OS, for both input and output.

For finding out which program is listening, this program is actually the driver of the
virtual adapter. Most operating systems have tools for displaying the details
of the installed adapters, which will include also the driver, as well as
the information that the driver chooses to expose.
Once the driver is identified, one can then know to which software product it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

> This is virtual so I imagine it's handled by some software.

It is, because it's a `utun*` interface. But note that this has nothing to do with it being a point-to-point interface (there can in theory be virtual Ethernet-like "tap*" interfaces as well).

> How does my machine actually know what 10.8.0.17 means? In other words, when it sees this as a gateway, what is the immediate next step? (I hope that makes sense)

The first steps are completely generic:

- For 'broadcast' interfaces (such as Ethernet or Wi-Fi), if a gateway is specified, the OS sends ARP or IPv6 NDP queries to determine the layer-2 address (MAC address), then sends the data frame with that destination address in the header.
- For 'point-to-point' interfaces, there is no layer-2 and no device to choose from, the IP packet is just sent as-is. If the route specifies a gateway IP address *and* a PtP interface, then the gateway address is just "for show".

*After* the routing table has been checked and the output interface (and MAC address) have been determined, the packet is passed further down to that interface's layer-1 driver. For example, if it goes through en0, it's given to the Ethernet card's driver. And if it goes through utun3, it's given to whatever program has actually created that interface.

(Usually the virtual interface is used much like a pipe in Unix. The program just tries to read() data from its end of the device, and any packets "sent" through utun3 will be read by the program. Whenever the program wants the OS to "receive" a packet, it writes the packet to the pipe. The exact functions vary between operating systems, though.)

After the VPN program reads the packet, it puts the entire thing (after encrypting it) inside a *new* packet with the VPN server as the destination (usually ordinary UDP or sometimes TCP). That packet goes through the entire process again.

> Is there a way for me to examine what handler might be listening in on requests to this interface?

I don't know this part, since it's very OS-specific. Someone else might. It seems like it might be possible to determine this [using some arcane options of ifconfig.](http://newosxbook.com/bonus/vol1ch16.html) (That page also shows that the networking mechanisms on macOS appear to be much more complex than I expected.)